# Swift 2 Error : new() is unavailable in Swift: use object initializers instead

Tags: ios, swift, view, swift2

2 working code under but when i checked it to swift 2 gives me this error :

```
ViewController.swift:55:50: 'new()' is unavailable in Swift: use object initializers instead
```

My all codes here

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.adBannerView?.adUnitID = kAdmobIDBanner
    self.adBannerView?.rootViewController = self
    var request = GADRequest()
    self.adBannerView?.loadRequest(request)

    var connection : APIConnection = APIConnection();
    MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    connection.startRequest(String(format:"%@getAllCuisines.php",kServerURl), responseBlock: { (data :[AnyObject]!) -> Void in

        var jsonResult: NSArray = data as NSArray;
        if((jsonResult.valueForKey("success").boolValue) == true)
        {
            self.dataArray = jsonResult.valueForKey("cuisine") as! NSArray
            self.tableview?.reloadData();
            MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(self.view, animated: true)

        }
        else
        {

        }

        }) { (error : NSError!) -> Void in
            MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(self.view, animated: true)
            //code
    }
    self.tableview?.tableFooterView = UIView.new() // HERE GIVES ERROR
}
```

I try everything but i didnt resolve it. Please help me

Comment: Can't you just call `self.tableview?.tableFooterView = UIView()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIView` doesn't have any property called `new()` in swift so you can directly assign `UIView` to your `tableFooterView` this way:

```
self.tableview.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Or you can assign any custom view to it.

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 1):

Calling new() is not the proper way to initialize objects in Swift. When creating an intance of a UIView usually you should write something like this:

```
 self.tableview?.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: aRect)
```

In your case you might want to initialize the view with CGRectZero